# NavigationView OnNavigationItemSelectedListener not being called

Tags: android, navigationview, android-support-design

I am trying to use [`NavigationView`](https://d.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView) from Android Support Design library in my app. For some reason, [`OnNavigationItemSelected`](https://d.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener) listener is not being called. Here is my code

Activity Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_frame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Activity onCreate()

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(getLayoutID());

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.activity_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.common_menu);
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_white_24dp);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(final MenuItem menuItem) {
            Snackbar.make(contentLayout, menuItem.getTitle() + " pressed", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            menuItem.setChecked(true);
            // allow some time after closing the drawer before performing real navigation
            // so the user can see what is happening
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            mDrawerActionHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    navigate(menuItem.getItemId());
                }
            }, DRAWER_CLOSE_DELAY_MS);
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            return true;
        }

    });
    usernameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_header_username);                  
    usernameTextView.setText(getAppDContext().getAccount().getUsername());
   }
```

Comment: Is there a reason for setting the listener twice on the NavigationView?

Comment: Oops. Pasted wrong code here. Corrected. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Post your full layout

Answer (score 70, accepted):

When you make XML layout, you should write down `NavigationView` after BaseLayout (`FrameLayout`, `LinearLayout`, etc..)

```
<DrawerLayout>
    <FrameLayout />
    <NavigationView />
</DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: This fixed a problem I had when exiting a full screen video in a `WebView` using the back button.  The `FrameLayout` was listed after the `NavigationView` in my XML file, and even though it was set as visibility `GONE` it was still covering up the `NavigationView` and preventing touches from being registered.

Answer (score 16):

For me this did the trick!

```
navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.bringToFront();
```

Answer (score 7):

Your activity main layout should look like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/navigationDrawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/activity_main_content" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        style="@style/NavigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In this NavigationView I linked header.xml and menu_drawer.xml (from menu folder)
for example menu_drawer.xml :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav1"
                android:checked="true"
                android:icon="@drawable/logo"
                android:title="Navigation item 1"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav2"
                android:icon="@drawable/logo"
                android:title="Navigation item 2"/>
        </group>
    </menu>
```

than your java code:

```
public class ActivityMain extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setUpToolbar();
        setUpNavDrawer();
    }

 private void setUpNavDrawer() {
        NavigationView view = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.navigationDrawer);
        view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawerOpen, R.string.drawerClose);
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
```

Check if this work for you. In my project works like a charm.

Comment: Does it call onOptionsItemSelected when hamburger icon is selected? No.
Also when I select a navigation item it is not calling the listener