# My Navigation View Item Listener Does Not Respond?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I need a side drawer layout, with a navigation view that contains a few buttons, doing different things. The issue I am having is that when I go to add ANYTHING within my "onNavigationItemSelected" listener, it never does anything. Basically, I assign the drawer+nav view, then do the ActionBarDrawerToggle with the proper items, and add the DrawerListener, then sync, then add the NavItemSelectedListener. This doesn't work. (Won't respond to clicks)
Here's the code:

```
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
toolbar = findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.open,R.string.close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
    private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment,String title) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in,
                            R.anim.fade_out,
                            R.anim.fade_in,
                            R.anim.slide_out)
            .setReorderingAllowed(true)
            .replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment,title)
            .addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
  @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        replaceFragment(new Auto(),"auto");
        return false;
    }
```

If this doesn't give a clear answer, here is ALL of the code for this task.

```
package com.gtappdevelopers.firebasestorageimage;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.gtappdevelopers.firebasestorageimage.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

import java.util.ArrayList;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    ActivityMainBinding binding;
    FloatingActionButton fab;
    static String balance = "NA";
    static int match = -1;
    static int team = -1;
    static String autoC = "NA";
    static String teleC = "NA";
    public static int dimen;
    static ArrayList<Integer> grid;
    static ArrayList<Integer> teleGrid;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        replaceFragment(new BeforeMatchFragment(),"before");
        fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);


        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.open,R.string.close);
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
         WindowManager manager = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        //initializing a variable for default display.
        Display display = manager.getDefaultDisplay();
        //creating a variable for point which is to be displayed in QR Code.
        Point point = new Point();
        display.getSize(point);
        //getting width and height of a point
        int width = point.x;
        int height = point.y;
        //generating dimension from width and height.
        dimen = Math.min(width, height);
        dimen = dimen * 3 / 4;

        fab.setOnClickListener(this);
        while (!checkPermission()) {
            requestPermission();
        }
        binding.bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.before:
                    replaceFragment(new BeforeMatchFragment(),"before");
                    break;
                case R.id.auto:
                    replaceFragment(new Auto(),"auto");
                    break;
                case R.id.tele:
                    replaceFragment(new TeleOp(),"tele");
                    break;
                case R.id.end:
                    replaceFragment(new EndGame(),"end");
                    break;
                case R.id.dock:
                    replaceFragment(new Docking(),"docking");
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id){
            case R.id.newTeam:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.FileViewer:
                Intent intent1= new Intent(MainActivity.this,FileListActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
                break;
            case R.id.NightMode:
                SplashActivity.setNight();
        }
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.fab:

                BeforeMatchFragment beforeFrag = (BeforeMatchFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("before");
                EndGame endFrag = (EndGame)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("end");
                Auto autoFrag = (Auto)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("auto");
                TeleOp teleFrag = (TeleOp)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tele");
                Docking dockFrag = (Docking)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("docking");

                if (beforeFrag != null && beforeFrag.isVisible()) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SplashActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else if (autoFrag != null && autoFrag.isVisible()) {
                    binding.bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.before);
                    replaceFragment(new BeforeMatchFragment(), "before");
                }else if (teleFrag != null && teleFrag.isVisible()) {
                    binding.bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.auto);

                    replaceFragment(new Auto(), "auto");
                }else if (endFrag != null && endFrag.isVisible()) {
                    binding.bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.dock);
                    replaceFragment(new Docking(), "docking");
                }else if (dockFrag != null && dockFrag.isVisible()) {
                    binding.bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.tele);
                    replaceFragment(new TeleOp(), "tele");
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment,String title) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in,
                            R.anim.fade_out,
                            R.anim.fade_in,
                            R.anim.slide_out)
            .setReorderingAllowed(true)
            .replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment,title)
            .addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
    public boolean checkPermission(){
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if(result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;

        }
    }
    private void requestPermission(){
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Storage permission is required, please allow it from settings.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},111);
        }
    }
    public static void setBalance(String balance) {
        MainActivity.balance = balance;
    }
    public static void setMatch(int match) {
        MainActivity.match = match;
    }
    public static void setTeam(int team) {
        MainActivity.team = team;
    }
    public static void setAutoC(String autoC) {
        MainActivity.autoC = autoC;
    }
    public static void setTeleC(String teleC) {
        MainActivity.teleC = teleC;
    }
    public static void setGrid( ArrayList<Integer> grid) {
        MainActivity.grid = grid;
    }
    public static void setTeleGrid( ArrayList<Integer> teleGrid) {
        MainActivity.teleGrid = teleGrid;
    }
    public static int getDimen() {
        return dimen;
    }
    public static int getMatch() {
        return match;
    }
    public static int getTeam() {
        return team;
    }
    public static String getAutoC() {
        return autoC;
    }
    public static String getTeleC() {
        return teleC;
    }

    public static String getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
    public static ArrayList<Integer> getGrid() {
        return grid;
    }
    public static ArrayList<Integer> getTeleGrid() {
        return teleGrid;
    }
    public static String getAllData(){
        return String.valueOf(match) + "\n" + String.valueOf(team) + "\n" + autoC + "\n" + grid.toString() + "\n" + teleC + "\n" + teleGrid.toString() + "\n" + balance;
    }
    public static void clearData(){
        match = -1;
        team = -1;
        autoC = "NA";
        grid = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
            grid.add(i,0);
        }
        teleC = "NA";
        teleGrid = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
            teleGrid.add(i,0);
        }
        balance = "NA";
    }



}
```

I have tried using a switch statement to detect which ID clicked the Item, but none worked. Then I tried making it so that ANY item that clicked the navigationView made the entire screen swap fragments. This did not work. Then, I tried getting a Toast.makeText() to show up when I clicked ANY Item, this did not work. I'm expecting the bug to be somewhere within my NavView set up/on create code.
EDIT: The answer was that within my  XML, my NavigationView was before my actual content within the screen. You must put the nav View AFTER the layout, be it relative, constraint, etc. It should be the last thing in the drawer layout, basically. This answer was given to me by Mike M. Thanks Mike!

Comment: It might be in your layout, actually. The drawer in a `<DrawerLayout>` should be listed last. That is, the `<NavigationView>` should be that last thing inside the `<DrawerLayout>` tags. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31397792.

Comment: Ah, yup. That fixed it. I had no idea. Thank you so much!!!